# VBA code to select active cell and update data in userform

Tags: vba

I have search box in userform, if value entered in search box refers to sheet1 column b10 then how to code b10 row as current row. I have coded this like

```
If Trim(Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value) = "," Then
ActiveCell = Cells(Me.TextBox_Search_Data)
ActiveCell.Activate

CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
```

But this code is neither giving any error nor activating current row

Comment: Why are you trying to `Activate` anything? `Select` and `Activate` are good for macro-recorder code; hand-crafted VBA code typically wouldn't need to `Activate` anything whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct. In `If` condition you are checking for "," in the text box. If it has comma then textbox cannot have cell value. May be you have to use some other textbox name in the `If` condition.

Try below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' best is to use Set wb = Workbooks("workbookname.xlsx")
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' you may use Set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    If Trim(Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value) <> "," Then
        sh.Range(Trim(Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value)).Activate
    End If

    Set sh = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```